# Total profit calculation java using arrays and various classes

Tags: java, arrays

[image]Hi I am new to programming and am struggling to figure out how to add the profits for the various items in a shop. I have a main method where the array of the items in the shop have been initialised. I have a separate method within the specific item class for calculating the profit but am not sure how to calculate a total profit for the same specific items classes, so I am trying to get the total profit for all food items and total profit for all stationery items, if that all makes sense. I am hoping there is a basic way of solving this issue as I am new to programming. it is probably really simple for more experienced programmers, but I am struggling getting me head round this.

Any direction or assistance would be appreciated?
many thanks

package shop;

public class Shop {

```
private String name;
private double sellingPrice, costPrice, amount, valueOfSoldItems, costPerMonth;
private int stockMonth, stockRem, volSoldMonth;

public Shop(String name, double sellingPrice, double costPrice, int stockMonth, int volSoldMonth) {
    this.name = name;
    this.sellingPrice = sellingPrice;
    this.costPrice = costPrice;
    this.stockMonth = stockMonth;
    this.volSoldMonth = volSoldMonth;

}

public double foodStats() {
    return getAmount();

}

public double stationeryStats() {
    return getAmount();
}

public void toolsStats() {

}
```

// Food Class

package shop;

public class Food extends Shop {

```
double totalProfit;

public Food(String name, double sellingPrice, double costPrice, int stockMonth, int volSoldMonth) {
    super(name, sellingPrice, costPrice, stockMonth, volSoldMonth);
}

public double foodStats() {

    System.out.printf("%-15s%-15s", "Food:   ", getName());
    System.out.printf("%-15s%-10s", "Selling Price:   £", getSellingPrice());
    System.out.printf("%-15s%-10s", "Cost Price:   £", getCostPrice());
    System.out.printf("%-15s%-10s", "Stock Ordered This Month:   ", getStockMonth());
    System.out.printf("%-15s%-10s", "Volume Sold this Month:   ", getVolSoldMonth());

    setStockRem(getStockMonth() - getVolSoldMonth());
    System.out.printf("%-10s%-5s", "Stock remaining:   ", getStockRem());

    setCostPerMonth(getCostPrice() * getStockMonth());
    setValueOfSoldItems(getSellingPrice() * getVolSoldMonth());

    if (getValueOfSoldItems() > getCostPerMonth()) {
        setAmount(getValueOfSoldItems() - getCostPerMonth());
        System.out.printf("%-10s%-5s", "  Profit:     £", getAmount());

    } else if (getCostPerMonth() > getValueOfSoldItems()) {
        setAmount(getCostPerMonth() - getValueOfSoldItems());
        System.out.printf("%-10s%-5s", "  Loss:       £", getAmount());

    } else {
        System.out.print("  No Profit No Loss! ");

    }
    return getAmount();
}
```

// Stationery class

package shop;

public class Stationery extends Shop {

```
public Stationery(String name, double sellingPrice, double costPrice, int stockMonth, int volSoldMonth) {
    super(name, sellingPrice, costPrice, stockMonth, volSoldMonth);

}

public double stationeryStats() {

    System.out.printf("%-15s%-15s", "Stationery:   ", getName());
    System.out.printf("%-15s%-10s", "Selling Price:   £", getSellingPrice());
    System.out.printf("%-15s%-10s", "Cost Price:   £", getCostPrice());
    System.out.printf("%-15s%-10s", "Stock Ordered This Month:   ", getStockMonth());
    System.out.printf("%-15s%-10s", "Volume Sold this Month:   ", getVolSoldMonth());

    setStockRem(getStockMonth() - getVolSoldMonth());
    System.out.printf("%-10s%-5s", "Stock remaining:   ", getStockRem());

    setCostPerMonth(getCostPrice() * getStockMonth());
    setValueOfSoldItems(getSellingPrice() * getVolSoldMonth());

    if (getValueOfSoldItems() > getCostPerMonth()) {
        setAmount(getValueOfSoldItems() - getCostPerMonth());
        System.out.printf("%-10s%-5s", "  Profit:     £", getAmount());

    } else if (getCostPerMonth() > getValueOfSoldItems()) {
        setAmount(getCostPerMonth() - getValueOfSoldItems());
        System.out.printf("%-10s%-5s", "  Loss:       £", getAmount());

    } else {
        System.out.print("  No Profit No Loss! ");
    }

    return getAmount();

}
```

}

// main class

package shop;

public class PrintShop {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Shop[] shops = new Shop[] { new Food("Jellies", 0.80, 0.30, 40, 35), new Food("Chocolate", 1.50, 1.80, 50, 45),
            new Food("Potatoes", 0.85, 0.25, 80, 70), new Stationery("Pens", 2.00, 1.00, 25, 18),
            new Stationery("Paper", 45.00, 23.00, 10, 4) };

    for (Shop shop : shops) {
        System.out.println(shop instanceof Food);
    }

    int shopDetails = 5;

    double foodProfit = 0;
    double stationeryProfit = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < shopDetails; i++) {
        Shop s = shop[i];
        if (shop instanceof Food) {
            foodProfit += shops[i].foodStats();
        } else {
            stationeryProfit += shops[i].stationeryStats();
        }
    }
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: isn't profit = (sellingPrice - costPrice) * volumeSold? just do that for your stationery and food after you have finished tabulated the Stats().

Comment: Hi Angel, I have tried a few variations on what you have suggested, although it doesn't seem to work. I already have a profit calculation in the foodStats section using if and else. Its a case of trying to figure out how to get one figure of all the foods profits added together even when there is a loss. Thanks

Comment: Note that it is generally discouraged to use doubles for money calculations, as their values might be inexact. Use `BigDecimal` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Ok whole edit of my answer.

First I advice you to really look deeper into inheritance because what you are trying to do is really awkward and in the future if you want to build it properly it comes at a really high cost.

I also post the necessary piece of code because it would be too big otherwise.

Some topic I would you to look further into:

- Inheritance
- Coding principle
- Naming
- Single Responsibility Principle

You hurt every single one of them and that is why your code is so hard to maintain. You can say that you will do it later or whatever but it will be a pain later on.

What do I mean:

Naming I already told you: Shop is for example not a good name and your previous array name shop1 is also not that good.

But yeah what is hurting you is the single coding principle.

In your function stationeryStats() and foodStats() happens so many things that it's hard to get what you want. It prints stuff, it calculate stuff, it sets new stuff and it return something. I don't even know what.
And it does set some stuff so I don't know what is with this thing.

An Object of the class Food / Stationery only knows his own parameter so that's why it can only show his own "stats". If you want to have a summary you have to place it where the information is known about all objects you have in the PrintShop but yeah I think it is still wrong this way.
You should really take your time and think about your design because it has so many flaw and nobody really knows what you want to do.

But here something like this to calculate the profit:

```
double foodProfit = 0;
double stationeryProfit = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < shopDetails; i++) {
    Shop shop = shops[i];
    if (shop instanceof Food) {
        foodProfit += shops.getProfit(); // you have to define the profit for each object how to calculate it, you can put it in the Shop class if the calculation for Food and Stationery is the same and then you don't need a cast.
    } else {
        stationeryProfit += shop.getProfit();
    }
}

System.out.println("Profit stationery: " + stationeryProfit);
System.out.println("Profit food: " + foodProfit);
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I appreciate there are a few issues and its not the best code at this point, still in progress, but it works for the moment. I am aware the int shopDetails should be = 5. I am not quite sure I understand how your answer is to aid me in figuring out how to add up the profits or losses and provide a single total figure for the food group & for the stationery group ? thanks your help is appreciated.

Comment: it helps you to figure out if the element in the array is of class Food or class Stationery. Add two new variable one which holds the sum of the Food profit the other for Stationery profit. After you check each element you add the profit to one of this variable.

Comment: @KyleEastwood if a post answered your question please accept it as an answer for people who read it in the future and may have a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

following up on what Boendal was saying.

your store list contains items from both food and stationery. so you will need to add them separately.

1) make your getFoodStats() and getStationeryStats() return the profit amount.

```
public double stationeryStats() { //changed the return
    //<snip-your printing parts> 
    //<snip calculations>

    return getAmount();   
}
```

2) then in your main function sum up the total for each item.

```
double foodProfit=0;
double stationeryProfit=0;

for (int i = 0; i < shopDetails; i++) {
    Shop shop = shop1[i];
    if( shop instanceof Food){  
       foodProfit += shop.foodStats();
    }else {
       stationeryProfit += shop.stationeryStats();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Angel, I have tried changing a few things but still seems to not work, I have updated the post to reflect more of the code including the error, hopefully this indicates where I am going wrong now ? I know this is prob straight forward and I seem to be missing something right in front of me. Thanks again. Regards

Comment: @KyleEastwood there are a few errors but you should be able to figure it out yourself though. Anyway: in the for loop change the line as follow: Shop shop = shops[i];   then in the if replace shops[i] with shop. In addition you have to be careful. The compiler think that shop is a Shop object, but Shop doesn't have a stationeryStats or a foodStats. So one way is to cast it into a Food object like this: foodProfit += ((Food)shop).foodStats() or define a method in Shop called showStats and implement his own version in each class with override. I suggest you read some guides about inheritance.

Comment: I made the suggested changes and it does print out, although it prints the same as the code I previously had, printing out a profit line for say each food item. Unless I am doing something wrong again. I am trying to print a single value showing the total profit or loss for all the food items. so it would add the individual food items profits and losses and produce one value for all the foods, if that makes sense ?

Comment: I have added an additional picture showing the individual profit and loss values for say 3 food items, to show what I am seeing.Now I would like those added and a single value displayed.

Comment: @KyleEastwood see my edit in my post but yeah I advise you to think about your design

Comment: Thanks for your comments many thanks I have re designed and it is a lot better and clearer now. All seems to be working well. Thanks all